# Magento 1.9.4 Product Collection by multible Sets and product type

Tags: magento

i have a product collection and want to filter by:

AttributeSet1, AttributeSet2, AttributeSet3

Where

1. AttributeSet1 shows only config. products
2. AttributeSet2 shows onyly grouped products
3. AttributeSet3 shows only simple products

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?